# write() is faster than read() in TCP Connection using Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I am experiencing issues where block of data written into a socket within a QTimer in a server application ,which can't be read by the client completely because the client's read process is slow, so when I stop the qtimer by clicking stop button ,the unread data failed to be read by the client.

**My Intensions :**

1. A Start Server button is clicked to start the server and then a connect button is clicked in by the client to connect to the host.
2. The input should be entered in the server window and the start button button is clicked in the client to increase the value by 1.(Frequency,Attenuation,Snr,Temperature)
3. After Increment, these values will be write in the socket inside QTimer and send to the client.
4. I used QByteArray and QDatastream for communication.The datas were send and received in blocks.
5. I used QTimer to populate my QWidgetTable.
6. After clicking Stop button by the client the increment process will be stopped.Finally by clicking didconnect button the client will be disconnected.
7. The Main point is the output values should be same in both server and client.

My intensions above mentioned were achieved successfully,expect point no.7  .The read process of the client is really slow, so when click the stop button it doesn't read the already written data by the server to the socket.I have more values in server window and less values in client window.

Any help will be appreciated !
Thank you in advance :)

**Left one is Client window and the right one is Server window:**
[image: Left side-Client window , Right side-Server window]

A part of my server code:

**Server.cpp**

```
void Server::readyRead()
{
nextBlockSize = 0;
QTcpSocket *client = (QTcpSocket*)sender();
qDebug() << client;
QDataStream in(client);
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_6_5);
if (nextBlockSize == 0) {
    if (client->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16))
        return;
    in >> nextBlockSize;
}
if (client->bytesAvailable() < nextBlockSize)
    return;

QString header;
QString cid;
QString footer;
in >> header;
in >> cid;
in >> footer;
if (cid == "0x1B10") {
    m_pWindow->addMessage("Client Connected");
}
if(cid =="0x1A10")
{
    m_pWindow->addMessage("Process Started");
    process();
}
 if(cid =="0x1A20")
{
    m_pWindow->addMessage("Process Stopped!");
    m_timer->stop();
}
 QDataStream out(client);
 out << quint16(0xFFFF);
 close();
 if(cid=="0x1B20")
 {
    m_pWindow->addMessage("Client Disconnected");
    disconnected();
 }

}

void Server::process()
{
m_timer = new QTimer(this);
connect (m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(passvalue())) ;
m_timer->start(1000);
}

void Server::passvalue()
{
m_pWindow->getinput();
}

void Server::increment(int freq, int att, int snr, int temp)
{
if(freq>=3000)
    freq=20;
if(att>=100)
    att=0;
if(snr>=10)
    snr=0;
if(temp>=30)
    temp=0;
freq++;
att++;
snr++;
temp++;
bool success=m_pWindow->updateTable(freq,att,snr,temp);

if(success)
{
    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_6_5);
    quint16 header=rand();
    quint16 payload1=freq;
    quint16 payload2=att;
    quint16 payload3=snr;
    quint16 payload4=temp;
    quint16 size=sizeof(payload1)+sizeof(payload2)+sizeof(payload3)+sizeof(payload4);
    quint16 footer=rand();
    out << quint16(0) << header << size << payload1 << payload2 << payload3 << payload4  << footer  ;
    uint16_t cs=checksum(block,size);
    out << cs;
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << quint32(block.size() - sizeof(quint16));
    foreach (QTcpSocket *socket, clients)
    {
        qDebug() << socket;
        socket->write(block);
        socket->waitForBytesWritten();
    }
}

}
```

A part of my client code :

**dialog.cpp**

```
void Dialog::readyRead()
{
nextBlockSize = 0;
QDataStream in(m_pClientscket);
m_pClientscket->waitForBytesWritten();
m_pClientscket->waitForReadyRead();
in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_6_5);
if (nextBlockSize == 0) {
    if (m_pClientscket->bytesAvailable() < sizeof(quint16))
        return;
    in >> nextBlockSize;
}
if (m_pClientscket->bytesAvailable() < nextBlockSize)
    return;
quint16 header;
quint16 payload1;
quint16 payload2;
quint16 payload3;
quint16 payload4;
quint16 size;
quint16 footer;
uint16_t cs;
updateTable(payload1,payload2,payload3,payload4);

}

void Dialog::updateTable(int freq,int att,int snr,int temp)
{
QTableWidgetItem *item;
ui->tableWidget->insertRow( ui->tableWidget->rowCount() );
for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
{
    item= new QTableWidgetItem;
    if(j==0)
        item->setText(QString::number(freq));
    if(j==1)
        item->setText(QString::number(att));
    if(j==2)
        item->setText(QString::number(snr));
    if(j==3)
        item->setText(QString::number(temp));
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(i,j,item);

}
ui->textEditFrequency->setText(QString::number(freq));
ui->textEditAttenuation->setText(QString::number(att));
ui->textEditSnr->setText(QString::number(snr));
ui->textEditTemp->setText(QString::number(temp));
i++;
}


void Dialog::on_pushButtonStop_clicked()
{
QByteArray block;
QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_6_5);
QString header="0x228";
QString cid="0x1A20";
QString footer="0x497";
out << quint16(0) << header << cid << footer  ;
out.device()->seek(0);
out << quint16(block.size() - sizeof(quint16));
m_pClientscket->write(block);
}
```

Comment: This is "normal" for sockets. When you write you write to a buffered mechanism, and the transmission is offloaded to a lower level of the network stack. So your write returns before the client has acknowledged receiving all of the data. The transport layer will later ensure all the data is (re)send to the client until the client acknowledges all data is received.

Comment: Ok .....but when the qtimer is stopped ,the socket is also closed and I don't know to retireve the unread data . I also tried waitforBytesWritten() before closing the socket ,but nothing changed. I am a newbie ...can you share your thoughts to make my client and server window same.

Comment: As a general advice: do not read directly from a socket with QDataStream. If you do that, error recovery is really hard, not to mention general troubleshooting. I don't even remember what QDataStream does with partial reads, the docs probably tell you that. But you don't need to worry about any of that, if you read the entire QDataStream-encoded block to a QByteArray first.

Comment: In other words, don't do this: `QDataStream in(client);`

Comment: And yes, `QDataStream` is a bit confusingly named. It's a serialization class, which just uses `<<` to add data, and `>>` to extract data. You still should create data packets with it, not use it as continuous stream. If you use it with a file, you can consider the whole file as a "data packet", but if you are operating on a TCP/IP stream, where all the data might not yet be available, it stops working. You need to wrap `QDataStream` packets inside your own protocol, for example 4 bytes for packet size, then packet data. And then you read entire packet before using QDataStream on it.

Comment: Ok I will implement it....but now can you plz help me to have same content in both client and server window?

Comment: @Belle As I said, on reading side you must not use QDataStream `>>` unless you are sure there is enough data. You need to read _correct amount_ of data to QByteArray first, that's the easiest way. Above I say one way to determine the correct amount of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **QByteArray** to read the data which is sent from the server to client using **readAll()** function.This solved my problem.

**dialog.cpp**

```
void Dialog::readyRead()
{
    QByteArray data = m_pClientscket->readAll();  // Read all available data
    QDataStream in(data);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_6_5);
    quint16 header;
    quint16 blocksize;
    quint16 payload1;
    quint16 payload2;
    quint32 payload3;
    quint32 payload4;
    quint16 size;
    quint16 footer;
    uint16_t cs;
    in >> header >> blocksize >> size >> payload1 >> payload2 >> payload3 >> payload4 >> footer >> cs   ;
    qDebug()  << header << size << payload1 << payload2 << payload3 << payload4 <<  footer << cs;

    updateTable(payload1,payload2,payload3,payload4);
}
```